# regext strip string with numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to strip everything from this URL except the 5 digit numbers.

I had this `[^\d]` but it does not strip the 1 from `ks1`.

URL:

```
/teaching-resources/primary-40069/ks1-maths-41582/understanding-shape-and-space-41616/position-and-direction-41619/
```

**Expected output**

```
40069 41582 41616
```

**Actual output** (pay attentio to unwanted initial **1** in `141582`):

```
40069 141582 41616
```

Comment: `[^\d]+` is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match` and then `join` instead of stripping:

```js
var re = /\b\d{5}\b/g; 
var str = '/teaching-resources/primary-40069/ks1-maths-41582/understanding-shape-and-space-41616/position-and-direction-41619/';
var m;
 
m = str.match(re).join(" ");

alert(m);
```